# macro: call parameter of level above - double pound ##1 doesn't work

Tags: macros, environments

Once again, I have a macro problem. It works almost. I spend a lot of time googling about `\expandafter`, `\noexpand`, `\unexpanded` and others. I used some of them, but nothing lead to the desired result.

If you find a better title for this problem, change it. I used the best, I could think of.

The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}



\makeatletter
%%%Liederbuch. This works!!!
\NewEnviron{Liederbuch}[1]{
\xdef\LB@my@temp{
\noexpand\newcommand{\csname LH#1\endcsname}[2]{
\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}
}
}
\aftergroup\LB@my@temp
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%The problem starts in the following Environ:

%If I replace `##1` and `##2` with constants, it works, but therefore it fails the basic intention of this effort.

%To see, what should happen, have a look at `\begin{document}`
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%Lied. This doesn't work!!!
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{%
    \ifnum\numexpr#2=\numexpr##2 % ##2 doesn't work; i.e. "1" instead of ##2 works
        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{##1}=0 % ##1 doesn't work; same as above
            \BODY
        \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother %residual of some tries with xdef and \aftergroup

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
%Apparently, the following code is super clean. That is the basic idea.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    

% This is a Liederbuch
\begin{Liederbuch}{songbook}
\begin{Lied}{t}{1}
Song 1 par t
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{n}{2}
Song 2 par n
\end{Lied}
\end{Liederbuch}


% LHsong calls "the environment" This works!!!
\newcommand{\LHsong}[3][n]{
\csname LH#2\endcsname[#1]{#3}
}


\begin{document}

%This should produce Song 1 par t
\LHsong[t]{songbook}{1}

%This shouldn't produce anything
\LHsong[n]{songbook}{1}

%This should produce Song 2 par n
\LHsong{songbook}{2}

%This shouldn't produce anything
\LHsong[t]{songbook}{2}

%This should also produce Song 1 par t
\LHsongbook{t}{1}

\end{document}
```

The Liederbuch expands to the following code which isn't part of my code

```
% it expands to:    %not part of the code
%Liederbuch
\newcommand{\csname LHsongbook\endcsname}[2]{
%Lied 1
    \ifnum1=\numexpr##2 %\numexpr#2 expanded to 1; ##2 should be par2 of newcommand
        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{t}{##1}=0 %#1 expanded to t
            Song 1 par t
        \fi
    \fi
%Lied 2 - same here different values
    \ifnum2=\numexpr##2
        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{n}{##1}=0
            Song 2 par n
        \fi
    \fi
}
```

I stole the Liederbuch-Environ from one of my other questions. The proof, that this works, can be seen by the change of ##x to constants. I suppose, that Lied should look similar, but I couldn't figure out, how.

The intention is, to have environment Liederbuch create a [perhaps series of] custom Lied environment[s] in which an invocation of \LHsong will produce output from Lied if the arguments match certain specifications.

Comment: Lots of code snippets are nice, but it would be better to provide a complete A to Z minimum working example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I thought about what would be better. I change it.

Comment: The definition of \LHsongbook` need not use `\csname`, of course; the arguments should be `#1` and `#2`: using `##1` is simply wrong.

Comment: @egreg Of course. That is not what the code is. That is what it expands to. I kept the `##x` to refer to the original code. The problem starts after the last comment line, which is displayed without scrolling down.

Comment: What you have written makes little sense to me, and you definitely are using `##` wrong (also `\newcommand` and `\NewEnviron` are not defined to be used that way). Could you expand on what do you want the code to do?

Comment: So that I understand your intention, you are hoping to have environment `Liederbuch` create a [perhaps series of] custom `Lied` environment[s] in which an invocation of `\LHsong` will produce output from `Lied` if the arguments match certain specifications.  Is that right?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Exactly.

Comment: @Manuel Steven got it. The environments are used in separate Liederbuch.sty files which will be `\usepackage`d. So I can include several Liederbuch-s and choose specific titles from all of them with only one command.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but: the [`leadsheets` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leadsheets) would allow you to print songs only if they match certain tags. So a separate file could contain the song definitions and in the main file said file is `\input` and a corresponding setup makes sure only those matching certain tags are actually printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is precisely what you want, but this does seem to work. I loaded `etoolbox` for convenience (`\csgdef`, `\csxdef`, `\csuse`).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\newenvironment{Liederbuch}[1]
  {\def\liederbuchtmp{#1}\csgdef{LH#1}##1##2{\csuse{lied;#1;##1;##2}}}
  {}
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{\csxdef{lied;\liederbuchtmp;#1;#2}{\expandonce\BODY}} % perhaps trimming spaces would be important
\newcommand*\LHsong[3][n]{\csuse{lied;#2;#1;#3}}

\begin{Liederbuch}{songbook}
\begin{Lied}{t}{1}
  Song 1 par t
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{n}{2}
  Song 2 par n
\end{Lied}
\end{Liederbuch}

\begin{document}

% This should produce Song 1 par t
\LHsong[t]{songbook}{1}

% This shouldnt produce anything
\LHsong[n]{songbook}{1}

% This should produce Song 2 par n
\LHsong{songbook}{2}

% This shouldnt produce anything
\LHsong[t]{songbook}{2}

% This should also produce Song 1 par t
\LHsongbook{t}{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test this as soon as possible. 
Until now, I avoided the etoolbox due to lack of understanding and for the reason, that I wanted to keep the package (later class) as primitive as possible.

Comment: I used it for simplicity, basically `\newcommand*\csxdef[1]{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname}`, `\newcommand*\csgdef[1]{\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname}`, and `\newcommand*\csuse[1]{\csname#1\endcsname}`.

Comment: I'd use `\expandonce\BODY` in order to avoid errors due to exhaustive expansion.

Comment: @clemens What means exhaustive expansion?

Comment: @Manuel: Do I get this right: You create for every new song a new command in which the parameters are part of the name. This is by far more elegant than my intended solution.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Yes, exactly. `\expandonce` is nice there to stop further expansion in `\xdef`.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz the expansion done bei `\edef` and friends (`\xdef`, `\write`, …). Placing user input in such a context is always dangerous since user input often contains fragile material (*i.e.*, material that leads to errors or erroneous output when placed in an `\edef`-like context).

Comment: @clemens I assume such a fault would happen, if I use `\egroup` which would expand in an edef to `}` and maybe cause a `missing \bgroup`. Is this correct?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz No. `\egroup` wouldn't expand. For instance an error might be raised if you have `\def\foo{}` inside, `\def` wouldn't expand because it's an unexpandable primitive, but `\foo` would be expanded, and if it's not defined it would raise an error. Take a look at LaTeX definition of robust and fragile commands.

Comment: @clemens I took a look recently, but I didn't understand it. So I postponed this topic in favor of more important things.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz something like `\textbf{a}` (standard user input, I'd say) already breaks inside an `\edef`. Try `\edef\foo{\textbf{a}}` and see what happens.