# \linebreak \\ causes error inside \BODY of \NewEnviron

Tags: macros, environments

I've got some code, which is mainly based on the solution of this:
[Other question I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304241/macro-call-parameter-of-level-above-double-pound-1-doesnt-work)
The code looks like this and it works so far, except for the `\\`-stuff:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


%%Environments
%Liederbuchumgebung
\newenvironment{Liederbuch}[1]
  {\def\liederbuchtmp{#1}\csgdef{LH#1}##1##2{\csuse{lied;#1;##1;##2}}}
  {}
%Liedumgebung
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{\csxdef{lied;\liederbuchtmp;#1;#2}{\BODY}}

%Forward to Environments
\newcommand*\LHsong[3][n]{\csuse{lied;#2;#1;#3}}


%use of Liederbuchenv.
\begin{Liederbuch}{Test}
%use of Liederbuchenv.
\begin{Lied}{t}{1}
%content begins here.
Lied Nummer 1, Format t
%Problem occurs here. If you delete the \\ it seems to throw a exhaustive expansion error (which I don't understand)
Hänschen klein, %\\
ging allein %\linebreak
in die weite Welt hinein. %\newline
Stock und Hut, 
steht im gut. 
Ist gar wohlgemut.
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{nt}{2}
Lied Nummer 2, Format nt
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{n}{336}
Lied Nummer 336, Format n
\end{Lied}
\end{Liederbuch}

\begin{document}
\LHsong[t]{Test}{1}
\end{document}
```

How can I get `\\` to work?

Comment: most latex commands are not safe in an  `\xdef`` why do you need edef expansion here? Note the comments on the referenced question already explain that such commands will fail in an xdef.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I use `\csdef`, it does't work, because it's out of scope. If I use `\csgdef` or `\global\csdef` I get an error, saying, it doesn't know `\BODY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most latex commands are not safe in `\xdef` (which is why latex has a `\protect` mechanism and `\protected@edef`) but here you just want `\let` I think and don't need to expand `\BODY` at all.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


%%Environments
%Liederbuchumgebung
\newenvironment{Liederbuch}[1]
  {\def\liederbuchtmp{#1}\csgdef{LH#1}##1##2{\csuse{lied;#1;##1;##2}}}
  {}
%Liedumgebung
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{\global\cslet{lied;\liederbuchtmp;#1;#2}\BODY}

%Forward to Environments
\newcommand*\LHsong[3][n]{\csuse{lied;#2;#1;#3}}


%use of Liederbuchenv.
\begin{Liederbuch}{Test}
%use of Liederbuchenv.
\begin{Lied}{t}{1}
%content begins here.
Lied Nummer 1, Format t
%Problem occurs here. If you delete the \\ it seems to throw a exhaustive expansion error (which I don't understand)
Hänschen klein, \\
ging allein %\linebreak
in die weite Welt hinein. %\newline
Stock und Hut, 
steht im gut. 
Ist gar wohlgemut.
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{nt}{2}
Lied Nummer 2, Format nt
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{n}{336}
Lied Nummer 336, Format n
\end{Lied}
\end{Liederbuch}

\begin{document}
\LHsong[t]{Test}{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understood this correctly, `\cslet` copies the content of `\BODY` into the csname.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz yes, well actually `\let` doesn't copy: `\let\a\b` makes `\a` have the same definition as `\b`

Comment: So, it's more like a pointer?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def/318#318